# Is there disadvantages to have the main scroll in a wrapper instead of in the body in HTML?

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

On many of my websites, in order to have nice transition between pages, I'm sometimes using a wrapper `div` with a `position:absolute` for my main scroll, instead of the body itself.

Here is a simple exemple:

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <div class="wrap">
     Content here
  </div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Is there any disadvantages to this? for SEO for exemple, or just a good practice? Or does it not matter at all?

Comment: I do this because it lets me write scroll effects that work in all browsers. One effect I've seen is in Google Search Console, using the "Fetch as Google" tool to try and see what the google crawler sees after all javascript is executed. It interprets my page as non-scrollable, with lower content hidden. This could affect SEO, but it's hard to predict exactly how.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: This question is completely fair. I have the exact same one. What are the caveats to having the scroll be on a DIV instead of on the HTML?